# How to stop a specific person to comment on my blog?

Tags: comments

I need to permanently prevent a specific person to comment on my blog on wordpress.com

How can I do this, please ?

My theme is iTheme2

Comment: WordPress.com questions are [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Have you tried the [WordPress.com support forums](http://en.support.wordpress.com/)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress.com support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People can always disguise their name or their IP address so the only foolproof way is to ensure that all comments are held for moderation then simply trash the comments from the person you wish to block.